# can not find protocol declaration of custom protocol when importing Appdelegate in viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I searched many ways but didn't find any answer. In my application i wrote a custom protocol in my view controller, and imported it into another view controller. When i build it, it throws an error that "protocol declaration is not found". I imported header files and the delegate properly, and shared appdelegate in one of my view controller.

I observed one thing, when I commented out `#import "AppDelegate.h"` in .h file of my view controller and `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` in .m file protocol works fine.

I am using ARC, and running on X-code 4.3.3 please help to get out of this problem.

in my application i have LoginViewController, after login user will go to viewController in which i added tabbar with five view controllers.tabbar view added to viewcontrolller view.

in viewController.m

```
[self.view addSubview:tabbars.view];
```

tabbar contains TodayViewController,setupViewController,statsViewController,guideViewController,helpViewController.

there is logout button in TodayViewController. when user clicks logout view should pops to loginViewController.for that i wrote a Protocol in today view controller.and imported in ViewController.

in one of my view controller 'timerViewController.h'  i imported `Appdelegate.h` and in 
timerViewController.m in wrote in viewDidload

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

when i comment Appdelegate.h in todayViewController.h and
`AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`

in todayViewController.m

works fine for me

but when i imported Appdelegate.h it throws error that "protocol declaration is not found"
 iam new to iphone please help me 
thank you.

Comment: Too little information to find this error.

Comment: i edited my Question above please see

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

When you access your app delegate, you have too *cast* it to the specific app delegate of you app.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = 
   (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: same problem remains. i changed as you suggested.but didn't worked for me.

Comment: So, where did you declare the @protocol?

Comment: in TodayViewController i declared Protocal.and i imported in viewController as  @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate,viewControllerDelegate>